# Qt: How to link form data with Table

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and would like to know how to link data from a form I created to a table.  I also created a QTableWidget.  I understand I would need to implement some SQL code, but I am wondering if there is a simple method to map the data.  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Look at `QSqlTableModel` and `QSqlQueryModel`. These are the simple way.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `QTableVIew` on top of a `QAbstractTableModel` is a good preferable solution if you want your application to be built with the MVC architecture. You need to create a new class which inherits the `QAbstractTableModel`. If so, there are some virtual functions such as `setData()`, `data()`, `rowCount()`, `columnCount()` and `headerData()` which you need to implement to populate the table with the database table.

I suggest you look into the following classes

- `QSqlDatabase`
- `QSqlQuery`
- `QAbstractTableModel`

After implementing the class which inherits `QAbstractTableMode`, you could setup a `TableView` widget and set its model to display the contents.

```
QTreeView *view = new QTreeView(this);
view->setModel(tableModel);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will work with this information and look into the classes you mentioned.

Comment: Just PM me if you need an example or something.